# If a paragraph overflows, can I break it into sentences?

Tags: html, css

In a website I'm writing, the footer has the form: `Copyright © 2019 David Corne. Git commit 23f1372a...`. It looks good on one line, but on mobile it breaks into two lines like this:

```
Copyright © 2019 David Corne. Git commit 
23f1372a...
```

which doesn't look as good. Is there a way for me to break it into

```
Copyright © 2019 David Corne. 
Git commit 23f1372a...
```

But only when it would split onto multiple lines. Link to github if that's helpful https://github.com/davidcorne/RecipeSite

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Add `<br>` to your text after the periods.

Comment: You can add a `<br class="hideOnMobile">` before 'Git commit' and control it through css. Give it a `display:none;` for PC screens and a `display:block;` for mobile screen through media queries.

Comment: Put non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` between the things you want to stay on the same line?

Comment: @HereticMonkey adding a `<br>` would always break there though, on desktop I would like it to be all on one line.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<br class="hideOnMobile">` before 'Git commit' and control it through media queries in css. Like that:

```
.hideOnMobile {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hideOnMobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exaclty what I needed, thanks! I've manually put the br in, and set it to show only on mobile.

Comment: @davidcorne Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `nowrap` to try to keep it on the same line:

```
.nobreak {
     white-space: nowarp;
}
```

Another band-aid that helps is using `&nbsp;` as the white-space

`&copy;&nbsp;&nbsp;2019&nbsp;&nbsp;David&nbsp;`

EDIT:  Sorry, I didn't answer your original question.  Yes, you can break it into two lines by forcing a line break with `<br/>` where you would like it to line-break

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is how I would do it:

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap
}

/* Note that in some cases you may need additional styles */
.nowrap {
  display: inline-block;/* necessary for nested inline elements */
  text-decoration: inherit;/* necessary for block/inline-block links */
  white-space: nowrap
}

/* It’s probably also good idea to disable this on very small screens */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .nowrap {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Copyright © 2019 David Corne. <span class="nowrap">Git commit 23f1372a...</span></p>
```